# Can you convert std::vector to std::array at compile-time without making the vector twice?

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr

I'm calculating some data at compile-time using `std::vector` and want to return the results as an array, so it can be used further at run-time. I'm having trouble setting the array size without doing the calculation twice.

Here's a simplified example of what I've done so far. The code compiles and works as expected.

```cpp
constexpr auto make_vector() { 
  // complex calculation here
  return std::vector{1, 2, 3}; 
}

constexpr auto make_array() {
  const auto vec = make_vector();
  std::array<int, make_vector().size()> result{};

  std::copy(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), result.begin());
  return result;
}

int main() {
  constexpr auto result = make_array(); // std::array<int, 3>{1, 2, 3}
}
```

I understand why it's not possible to use `vec.size()` for the array size and why `make_vector().size()` produces a compile-time constant. It just doesn't seem the *right* approach to do it twice.

Is there a way to avoid calling `make_vector` twice? Am I missing a basic concept here?

Comment: I don't think calling it twice has a big impact, this should be the only concise way to do it.

Comment: @康桓瑋 In my project `make_vector` is a complex calculation, it's just a one-liner in the example above.

Comment: Maybe what we need is *partially* `constexpr` structured bindings, such as `auto [vec, constexpr size] = make_vector();`

Comment: you know at compile time how many elements the vector has, why dont you just use array directly, instead of this complicated copying?

Comment: @Red.Wave won't compile, see "transient allocation"

Comment: @Raildex I know the final size when the calculation is done, so this is not an option.

Comment: I think calling the function twice is the only option. I would test (by profiling?) if your compiler actually repeats the calculation or not, maybe it manages to memoize the result.

Comment: @local-ninja, can you elaborate more on why the size of `make_vector()` isn't just a `constexpr std::size_t` provided by the code that exposes `make_vector()` itself? I mean, in order to use `make_vector()` in a constant expression, the size of the returned `std::vector` must be known at compile time (at least in the `constexpr` path), regardless of `// complex calculation`.

Comment: @local-ninja, in other words, what I'm saying is that _I know the final size when the calculation is done_ makes little sense, because if the size `make_vector().size()` was not known at compile time, you couldn't be using it as a template arg to `std::array`. So that size _can_ be returned as a separate thing, by a separate `constexpr` function, say `get_size()` by the same code that exposes `make_vector()`. In your actual code, this `get_size()` is in a way scattered thoughout the implementation of `make_vector()`, one way or another. You can pull it out.

Comment: @Enlico Say the calculation constantly pushes new elements to the vector. The `constexpr get_size()` you are suggesting basically requires repeating the expensive calculation (at compile time). Simple example, `make_vector(int n)` can be a function that returns a vector containing all non-negative numbers `k` not greater than `n` that satisfies a predicate `f(k)`, where `f` is a very expensive function.

Comment: @WeijunZhou, that's incorrect. The number of pushes though the `constexpr` path would still be `constexpr` itself, and can be pulled out. All of that can be done once at compile time. And the result put in a `std::array`. The OP hasn't really explained why `std::vector` is necessary at all.

Comment: It can be pull out, so what? You can use it to initialize a constexpr variable, but you have no way to write it in a template parameter without repeating the calculation. What you're suggesting is basically equivalent to using `vec.size()` in the template parameter, which OP already knows does not work. If you still think it can be done, show me some code, e.g. for the problem I stated above, and you don't have to use `std::vector` if you don't want to.

Comment: @Enlico The output size can't be calculated separately from the actual computation. It's the same operation, just as WeijunZhou said. Splitting makes no sense, both algorithms would be identical.

Comment: @local-ninja thanks. I was wondering what `constexpr` meant  on a `std:: vector` constructor. Good reminder and explanation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Is there a way to avoid calling `make_vector` twice? Am I missing a basic concept here?

Currently, no. The fundamental issue is that `std::vector` is not a literal type, so you cannot simply store it in a `constexpr` variable where its size and contents can be used arbitrarily. A `std::vector` can only live temporarily during a constant expression<sup>(1)</sup>.

During this first constant expression, the `.size()` is not a constant expression, and there's no way to "elevate it to that status".
Therefore, you don't know the size of the array you're creating, and the vector contents are wasted the first time<sup>(2)</sup>.

This issue is also the motivation in [P0784: More constexpr containers](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0784r7.html)<sup>(3)</sup>:

> Amongst other things, the lack of variable size [constexpr] containers forces them to use primitive fixed-size data structures in the implementation, and to parse the input JSON string twice; once to determine the size of the data structures, and once to parse the JSON into those structures.

You're not the first to run into this problem, and you'll just have to be patient until the C++ committee and compiler developers figure this one out.

The latest paper addressing this problem is [P1974: Non-transient constexpr allocation](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2670r1.html). The key issue is that any `T*` allocated at compile time and stored in a `constexpr` variable (directly, or through a container) can point to mutable memory. This constness issue means that a `constexpr std::vector<std::string>` would contain a mixture of mutable/immutable pointers (akin to `char ** const`), and that breaks the assumption that we can omit `delete` entirely and keep static memory instead. Refer to the paper for more details.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> The reason is that even though `std::vector` can use `new` in constant expressions, all memory must be de-allocated before the end of the constant expression. This is referred to as "transient allocations".

<sup>(2)</sup> As commenter @HolyBlackCat has pointed out, it's possible that your compiler memoizes the call to `make_vector()` so that even though you call it twice, the function doesn't need to be evaluated twice.

<sup>(3)</sup> This paper has been accepted into C++20, but does not yet solve the issue with wasted container creation.

Answer (score 1):

> The output size can't be calculated separately from the actual computation.

Good, but since it is at compile time, you can do all of that with `std::integer_sequence` (or `std::index_sequence`, if the type of the elements is `std::size_t`) and some metaprogramming.

Then, if you really need a `std::array`, you can make the conversion with this:

```cpp
template<typename N, N ...ns>
consteval auto seq2array(std::integer_sequence<N, ns...>) {
      return std::array{ns...};
}
static_assert(seq2array(std::index_sequence<1, 2, 3>{}) == std::array<std::size_t, 3>{1, 2, 3});
```

Now, how to generate the `std::index_sequence` depends on what the "complex calculation" is.

Weijun Zhou suggested in a comment a toy example:

> `make_vector(int n)` can be a function that returns a vector containing all non-negative numbers `k` not greater than `n` that satisfy a predicate `f(k)`, where `f` is a very expensive function.

What does it take to do that?

Well, that just means filtering the sequence of numbers from `0` inclusive to `n` exclusive, with the predicate `f`.

Let's invent the predicate

```cpp
constexpr auto f = [](auto k) {
    // expensive compuptation
    return k % 2 == 0;
};
```

and write a filtering utility. For the latter we need a recursive approach where we apply the predicate to the first element of the sequence to decide whether to keep it or not, make a singleton or empty sequence out of it respectively, and concatenate with the rest of the filtered sequence.

So the first thing we need is actually a way to concatenate sequences. Here it is:

```cpp
template<typename N, N ...ns, N ...ms>
consteval auto cat(std::integer_sequence<N, ns...>, std::integer_sequence<N, ms...>) {
    return std::integer_sequence<N, ns..., ms...>{};
}
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(cat(std::index_sequence<1, 2>{}, std::index_sequence<3, 4>{})), std::index_sequence<1, 2, 3, 4>>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(cat(std::index_sequence<1, 2>{}, std::index_sequence<>{})), std::index_sequence<1, 2>>);
static_assert(!std::is_same_v<decltype(cat(std::index_sequence<2, 2>{}, std::index_sequence<3, 4>{})), std::index_sequence<1, 2, 3, 4>>);
```

Finally, we need the filtering utility.

```cpp
template<typename Seq, typename Pred>
struct Filter {};

template<typename N, N n, N ... ns, typename Pred>
struct Filter<std::integer_sequence<N, n, ns...>, Pred> {
    using head = std::integer_sequence<N, n>;
    using tail = typename Filter<std::integer_sequence<N, ns...>, Pred>::type;
    using type = std::conditional_t<Pred{}(n), decltype(cat(head{}, tail{})), tail>;
};

template<typename N, typename Pred>
struct Filter<std::integer_sequence<N>, Pred> {
    using head = std::integer_sequence<N>;
    using type = head;
};

template<typename N, N ...ns, typename Pred>
consteval auto filter(std::integer_sequence<N, ns...>, Pred) {
    return typename details::Filter<std::integer_sequence<N, ns...>, Pred>::type{};
}
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(filter(std::index_sequence<>{}, f)), std::index_sequence<>>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(filter(std::index_sequence<1, 2, 3, 4>{}, f)), std::index_sequence<2, 4>>);
```

With all of that in place, our `make_vector`, which I'm renaming `make_array` can be written like this

```cpp
template<std::size_t n>
consteval auto make_array() {
    return seq2array(filter(std::make_integer_sequence<std::size_t, n>{}, f));
}
```

and used like this

```
static_assert(make_array<10>() == std::array<std::size_t, 5>{0, 2, 4, 6, 8});
```

---

Notice that the abstractions `filter` and `cat` defined above are very general, and could be used in many other cases, so they can be part of a library. That would justify the amount of boilerplate, which is anyway not that much.

Comment: This is good, except that the size is limited by the available number of template arguments (at least 256, but for some implementations it's just 256). Upvoted anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[Jarod's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77689769/3966456) has given detailed explanation for why in the current c++ language standard it is impossible to convert a vector to an array without additional helper functions. However, if an upper bound of the size of the vector can be calculated in a relatively simple way, it is still possible to convert the vector to an array by first constructing a larger array. In essence, this is constructing a literal type that contains all the information of the vector and that can be used to construct the actual array later.

Assuming that we have

```
template <int N>
constexpr std::size_t upper_bound_for_make_vector(); //Should be cheap to calculate

template <int N>
constexpr std::vector<int> make_vector();
```

We can build a literal type which can be used as a NTTP by modifying the implementation of OP's code a little.

```
template <int N>
constexpr auto make_array_size_pair() {
  const auto vec = make_vector();
  std::array<int, upper_bound_for_make_vector<N>()> result{};

  std::copy_n(vec.cbegin(), vec.size(), result.begin());
  return std::pair{result, vec.size()};
}
```

Then we can use the result as a NTTP to construct the actual array,

```
template <auto arr_pair>
constexpr auto trim_array(){
  std::array<int, arr_pair.second> result{};
  static_assert(arr_pair.first.size() >= result.size());
  std::copy_n(arr_pair.first.cbegin(), result.size(), result.begin());
  return result;
}
```

With these helpers, we can write our `make_array` function.

```
template <int N>
constexpr auto make_array(){
  return trim_array<make_array_size_pair<N>()>();
}
```

Although this solution is not limited by the total number of template parameters (which can be as low as 256), it may be desired to make `trim_array` `consteval` to prevent generating an extremely long symbol name of no other use.

Comment: In principle, if the output size could be calculated separately, the problem would not exist. Trimming the upper bound is an improvement. However, it does not completely solve the original problem. For the current state of the standard it's a nice alternative. Thanks!