Compute std::vector in consteval context and copy values to std::array in C++20 or later
I am trying to utilize std::vector, which has constexpr member functions since C++20, for compile-time calculations with a statically knowable but non-obvious number of values and then carry those values over to runtime by writing them into an array.
I understand that I cannot directly carry the vector over into the runtime context because everything that was allocated at compile-time must be deallocated at compile-time. I also understand that I need a function template at at least one point because function's return types cannot depend on the argument.
This is my attempt.
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

consteval std::vector<int> primes_helper(int n) {
    std::vector<int> v;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
        bool prime = true;
        for (int j = 2; j * j <= i; ++j) {
            prime = prime && (i % j != 0);
            if(!prime) break;
        }
        if(prime) v.push_back(i);
    }
    return v;
}

template <int N>
consteval auto primes() {
    constexpr auto primes = primes_helper(N);
    std::array<int, primes.size()> out;
    for(int i = 0; i < primes.size(); ++i)
        out[i] = primes[i];
    return out;
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto p = primes<1000>();
    std::cout << p.size() << "\n";
    return 0;
}

Computing prime numbers is a toy example, what I'm trying to understand is, why the compiler complains that primes in primes() is supposedly not initialized by a constant expression and what modifications would be necessary to make it work.
A modified version that essentially duplicates the logic but still calls the helper function to obtain the array size (https://godbolt.org/z/nzYGKK83P) works.

You just need to remove the constexpr before primes. It doesn't belong there. You want p to be initialized by a constant expression, not primes which is an intermediate step of the calculation.

You can't use primes.size() though. You need to repeat the calculation in the template argument, precisely because you can't store the vector as a compile-time constant, i.e. primes.size() -> primes_helper(N).size().

@user17732522 Thanks for the response. If I remove the constexpr before primes, I cannot use primes.size() as a template parameter for std::array<int, primes.size()> out. The length of the result depends on the compile-time computation.

See my comment above. Also, there isn't any reason to use consteval here. constexpr everywhere will have the same effect. consteval is only useful if you want to make sure the function is compile-time evaluated even if not used to initialize a constexpr variable or if you want to explicitly disallow using the function at runtime.

Thanks. I see the issue now. Your comment also helped me find that that my question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77689295/can-you-convert-stdvector-to-stdarray-at-compile-time-without-making-the-vec/77689769 which I didn't find before.
